# calculate the percentage of difference of each element with others in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array const arr = [1,2,3,6,7]. I want to calculate the percentage of difference of each element with others in the array.
For example:
**1** is 100% of arr[0], 50% of arr[1], 33.33% of arr[2], 16.66% of arr[3];
**2** is 200% of arr[0], 100% of arr[1], 66.66% of arr[2], 33.33% of arr[3] etc...
Can someone help me solve this problem or at least give a hint?
I'm very glad your any answers.

Comment: Hint: Use nested loops.

Comment: Both loops iterate over the array elements. One loop gets the numerator, the other gets the denominator.

Comment: 2 is 50% of arr[0], 100% of arr[1], right?

Answer (score 0):

I am just practicing my JavaScript so took your project on as a little test.

I have developed a solution below that works. Feel free to ask me questions :)

```
const inputFunc = (num) => {

 const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
 let newArr = []
 for(let i = 1; i < arr.length + 1; i++){
  let result = num / i * 100
  if(String(result).length >= 4){
   newArr.push(`${result.toFixed(2)}%`)
  }
  else{
   newArr.push(`${result}%`)
  }
 }
 for(let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
  console.log(newArr[i])
 }
}
inputFunc(1)
```